# Client Server chat application in java

Tags: java, mysql

I have developed a LAN client server chat application in java .Now my server also establishes a connection with mysql database which i use to store files of any type.Now my problem is i want to retrieve  file from database and be able to transfer that file to the client.Can anyone tell me how can this be done.I know how to retrieve the file from database and i am not understanding how to send it to the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using sockets then take an output stream from socket and write your file bytes into that output stream.
just read from database and send it to that socket which is connected to other side.

Comment: -Yes i am using sockets i did try what you said but i am not able to send file can you please elaborate a little more.

Comment: Can anyone please guide me?

Comment: in what format you have saved file into database?
and how you are accessing that file? are you using JDBC?

Comment: yes i am using JDBC.I have saved the file in mysql as a BLOB.

Comment: see the sample code

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1];
      InputStream is = resultSet.getBinaryStream(index);
      while (is.read(buffer) > 0) {
        socket_output_stream.write(buffer);
      }
      fos.close();